# Как работает метод System.runFinalization()?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Из одной статьи

> System.runFinalization() создает второй поток "SecondaryFinalizer", который также вызывает finalize() для объектов из той же очереди, при этом поток, вызвавший System.runFinalization() ждёт, пока не кончится очередь Finalizer, которая имеется на данный момент.

Я здесь не понял, он будет работать параллельно? Или же всё таки дождётся окончания первого потока и продолжит, но тогда какой толк от этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря, детали реализации метода `runFinalization` скрыты в используемой реализации VM, и делать этот метод может самые разные вещи. К примеру, IKVM при вызове `runFinalization` просто запускает `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`.

В статье, которую вы читали, наверное говорится про Oracle JVM.

Secondary Finalizer будет работать параллельно с основным потоком финализации. При этом поток, который вызвал `runFinalization` будет спать пока работает Secondary Finalizer.

Новый поток делается для того, чтобы предоставить всем финализаторам одинаковый объем стека, не зависящий от того, сколько стека вы успели "потратить" при вызове `runFinalization`.

---

Для упрощения, можете считать что `runFinalization` просто запускает все оставшиеся финализаторы подряд. Это практически неотличимо от наблюдаемого поведения.

Comment: да, говорится о HotSpot VM